# Spring Cloud Stream - Testing Functional Producer

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I wrote a Spring Cloud Stream Producer according new functional model introduced with 3.1 version.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Component
public class Producer {
    private final BlockingQueue<Message<Object>> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void produce(int messageId, Object message) {
        Message<Object> toProduce = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(message)
                .setHeader(PARTITION_KEY, messageId)
                .build();

        messageQueue.offer(toProduce);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<Object>> produceMessage() {
        return () -> messageQueue.poll();
    }
}
```

I'm able to call from a REST controller the `produce(int, Object)` method that put data into the `BlockingQueue`.
The `Supplier`, annotated with `@Bean`, annotation is polled by default every second.

This is a snippet of the application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: produceMessage
    stream:
      bindings:
        produceMessage-out-0:
          destination: test-topic
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
            partitionKeyExpression: headers['partitionKey']
            partitionCount: 1
            errorChannelEnabled: true
...
     kafka:
        bindings:
          produceMessage-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 10
                max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 1
                request.timeout.ms: 20000
```

Finally I wrote this class in order to test my code:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ProducerTest {

    @Test
    void producerTest() {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder
                (TestChannelBinderConfiguration.getCompleteConfiguration(Producer.class))
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .run("--spring.jmx.enabled=false")) {
            OutputDestination output = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);

            Producer producer= context.getBean(Producer.class);
            producer.produce(1, new MyMessage(1, "Hello Message"));

            Message<byte[]> received = output.receive();
            Assertions.assertNotNull(received);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test, it fails because `received` is null.
I read a lot of examples that show this is the way to test this type of Producer.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me please?
Thanks